# how to save a downloaded file into internal storage in android?

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager, android-internal-storage

i have used the below code to download a video from server in android studio and it works correctly , but when i search the video in my device i cant find it anywhere ... where does it save and how can i change destination directory on "internal storage"?

```
private DownloadManager downloadManager;

btn_download_video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlVideo);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(Video_detail_Activity.this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, videoName);
            Long reference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

        }
 });
```

i used below permissions in my project too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: you can use for example `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` or similar `DownloadManager.Request` methods

Comment: check the download folder

Answer (score -2, accepted):

thanks for helping ... as [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) said i changed

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(Video_detail_Activity.this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, videoName);
```

to

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS.toString(), videoName+".mp4");
```

and now i can see downloaded file in "Download" folder.

Comment: what about the second question? how can i change destination directory on "internal storage"

Comment: For those coming here now, this will not save the file to the internal storage as the question was asking originally.